# VB Collections, Arrays, Iterations, and Queires

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net, collections, iteration

Can someone Help me improve the code below? I just know once I see how iterations, arrays, and collections are properly used for situations like the code im writing below, I'll be able to write more efficient programs.

```vb
 Private Sub GetStackRanking()
    Dim SortOrder As String = lblSortOrder.Text


    If lblShowRouteDelivery.Text = "ROUTES" Then

        If lblShowYTDWeekly.Text = "YTD" Then
            'STACK 1\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank1 As String = "SELECT SELECT(EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank1Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank1, MySQLConnection)
            'OPEN CONNECTION
            If MySQLConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                MySQLConnection.Open()
            End If
            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank1Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank1Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank1Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank1Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk1.Text = CType(StackRank1Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk1.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank1Reader.Close()

            'STACK 2\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank2 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank2Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank2, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank2Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank2Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank2Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank2Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk2.Text = CType(StackRank2Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk2.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank2Reader.Close()

            'STACK 3\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank3 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank3Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank3, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank3Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank3Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank3Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank3Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk3.Text = CType(StackRank3Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk3.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank3Reader.Close()

            'STACK 4\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank4 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank4Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank4, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank4Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank4Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank4Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank4Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk4.Text = CType(StackRank4Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk4.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank4Reader.Close()

            'STACK 5\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank5 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank5Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank5, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank5Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank5Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank5Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank5Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk5.Text = CType(StackRank5Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk5.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank5Reader.Close()

            'STACK 6\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank6 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank6Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank6, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank6Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank6Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank6Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank6Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk6.Text = CType(StackRank6Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk6.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank6Reader.Close()

            'STACK 7\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank7 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank7Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank7, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank7Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank7Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank7Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank7Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk7.Text = CType(StackRank7Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk7.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank7Reader.Close()

            'STACK 8\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank8 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk7.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank8Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank8, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank8Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank8Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank8Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank8Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk8.Text = CType(StackRank8Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk8.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank8Reader.Close()

            'STACK 9\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank9 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk7.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk8.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank9Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank9, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank9Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank9Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank9Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank9Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk9.Text = CType(StackRank9Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk9.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank9Reader.Close()

            'STACK 10\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
            Dim StackRank10 As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = " & lblAreaOBJID.Text & " AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk1.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk2.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk3.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk4.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk5.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk6.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk7.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk8.Text & "' AND EMPLOYEE_NAME <> '" & LblStckRnk9.Text & "' GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME ORDER BY YIELD " & lblSortOrder.Text & ""
            Dim StackRank10Conn As New SqlCommand(StackRank10, MySQLConnection)

            'READ DATA FROM CONNECTION AND DISPLAY IT
            Dim StackRank10Reader As SqlDataReader = StackRank10Conn.ExecuteReader()
            If StackRank10Reader.HasRows Then
                While StackRank10Reader.Read
                    LblStckRnk10.Text = CType(StackRank10Reader.Item(0), String)
                End While
            Else
                LblStckRnk10.Text = "---"
            End If
            'CLOSE CONNECTIONS
            StackRank10Reader.Close()
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So much bad here :( You can't use a MySqlConnection (for MySql) with an SqlCommand (for Sql Server). What kind of database are you working with?. The SQL statement is not even close to valid for any database. You don't correctly parameterize your queries, leaving you open to horrible sql injection attacks. And you don't correctly close your connections.

Comment: Joel, These are the ignorant mistakes I need to fix. I never had any formal training on connection strings and queires so all these mistakes are from googling what works. I might add that im a straight up rookie but Im learning. with help...

Comment: Don't put your entire function as is here, narrow down the problem and only post the applicable part of it, and actually tell us what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things with that code that are just plain broken in confusing ways (mixing MySql with Sql Server ado.net provider objects, for example). The best I can hope to do for you right now is give you an example of something that looks kind of right.

```vb
Private Function GetStackRanking1(ByVal AreaObjectID As Integer) As String

    Dim sql As String = "SELECT EMPLOYEE_NAME, AVG(EFFICIENCY_YIELD) AS YIELD FROM dbo.APE_BUSDRIVER_MAIN WHERE APE_AREA_OBJID = @AreaObjectId GROUP BY EMPLOYEE_NAME"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("connection string here"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AreaObjectId", SqlDbType.Integer).Value = AreaObjectId
        cn.Open()
        Return CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
   End Using
End Function
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
LblStckRnk1.Text = GetStackRanking1(Integer.Parse(lblAreaOBJID.Text))
```

Note that user interface objects are not anywhere part of the method that calls to the database. Also notice the `Using` block. This ensures the connection will be closed, *even if an exception is thrown*. Most of all, notice how the Area Object ID is sent to the query. This will prevent any possibility of sql injection.

Comment: yeah. I was using an MS Database before i switched to an SQL database. nevertheless, Thank you very much for you input!

Comment: You're a genius! What you just showed me opens up a whole new door for me. Thanks!